# How to use cpulimit to a python script

Tags: python

From the answer to my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547734/python-write-dynamically-huge-files-avoiding-100-cpu-usage), I gone through [this](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) and some more from google. But I did not understand, how can I `cpulimit` for a python script.
Followings are my try:

```
cpulimit --limit 20 --exe ./read_heavy_csv.py

cpulimit --limit 20 --exe "python read_heavy_csv.py" 

cpulimit -P ./read_heavy_csv.py -l 20
```

and some more...

But in each case getting warning :

```
Warning: no target process found. Waiting for it...
```

I could not find any documentation to explain running a python script with `cpulimit`. I also gone through [these too](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=QTHMVq7DIrLG8Afr36vwAw#safe=active&q=cpulimit%20python%20script) but did not get any clue

Comment: `cpulimit` does not launch the process, it searches for it.  So is your python program already running when you run `cpulimit`?  If not, then it should be.  Specifying the pid is probably safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing a program, `cpulimit` limits the cpu usage of running process. You need to run the program separately.

Run the program normally:

```
python read_heavy_csv.py
```

Open other terminal, and run the following command (`pgrep ...` will give you the pid of the previous command)

```
cpulimit --limit=10 -p `pgrep -f read_heavy_csv\.py`
```

Please note that pgrep uses RegEx patterns, not simple strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

cpulimit --limit 50 -- python /explicit-path-to-file/extractSift.py start